# Does PrimeFaces 3.0 and / or jsf 2.0 supports SDK 1.4?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Can you guys tell me whether the primefaces 3.0 and / or jsf 2.0 will support JDK 1.4 ?

Comment: JDK 1.4 entered EOL at end of 2006 which completed at end of 2008. JSF 2.0 was introduced at end of 2009. Surely it won't support an EOL'ed JDK version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Primefaces 3.0 documentation:

> PrimeFaces only requires a JAVA 5+ runtime and a JSF 2.x
>   implementation as mandatory dependencies.

JSF 2.0 alone needs at least Java EE5, JSF 2.1 Java EE6

Comment: In other words, the answer is "no".

Comment: You are welcome. Since you are new here, please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted ([more information on accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/161675))